# Joda type def loading fails during hibernate init 

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jodatime

Joda time in pair with hibernate support is used. Configuration is as follows:

There's typedefs in ***org.joda.time.package-info.java***:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs({
 @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(
                        name="localDate",
                        typeClass =
org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDate.class
        )
})
package org.joda.time;
```

There's a spring context with session factory config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>org.joda.time</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>...</value>
...
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Then there's test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:spring-test.xml"})
@Transactional
public class OperatorDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
//autowired dao field defined
...
@Test
public void testMethod(){
//calls DAO method
}
}
```

Problem is in next exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: localDate, at table: TABLE_NAME, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(DATE_COLUMN)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use standard Date to map to database, and then in my getter/setter I use joda-time and perform the conversion, to avoid issues like you are having. [This may be of use](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=499).

Comment: Thanx for answer, but following your advice involves too much effort, it's easier to use a different workaround, like adding type definition property to session factory.

Comment: A weak workaround, in my opinion, and doesn't really solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @rtcarlson thanks for the comment/vote, maybe you could suggest a less weak answer ?